# Does PersistentStore\PersistentObject data remain after updating app from AppWorld

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-world

I am wondering whether the data which was stored in `PersistentObject\PersistentStore` remains after updating a version of an application.

My use case:

1) Publishing  application  with version 0.1. Users save data into PersistentObject\PersistentStore

2) Publishing application with version 0.2.

**Will the data that was saved into PersistentStore\PersistentObject in version 0.1 be available to the application with version 0.2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will still be available so long as the classes that are persisted have not had any structural changes.  This means you can't add or delete fields between versions if you want the persistent data to remain.

Comment: Thank's for reply. I would like to sum up gained knowledge: if I save data in PersistentStore as Object during upgrading the application version the data cleared. But if I serialize the Object to the String and save object as string  in PersistentStore this string won't be cleared and updated version of application will be able to read and parse data. This solution has a drawback: if application is being uninstalled the data from PersistentStore will be leaved on devices, data won't be cleared during uninstall. Also not ver good.

Comment: If, I am going to change in all files for App, what will happen?
Will persistent be there or will cleared for the App?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to ensure this works smoothly when updating the app is to store all your persistent data in a hashtable.  Each piece of data will be stored by a string **key**.  You retrieve values by that string key.  New versions of the app are able to add new persistent data, simply by adding objects, with new string keys.

This allows you some future flexibility, while not having problems with the basic format of your persistent classes changing, [as Michael warned about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10574547/119114).  Your data will **always** be in a persistent `Hashtable`.

If you want to make sure that the persistent data is deleted when your app gets deleted, then use a hashtable container that's unique to your app's *package*:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Preferences extends Hashtable implements Persistable {
```

An instance of this `Preferences` class, for example, is what you'll pass to `PersistentObject#setContents()`.

If you **don't** want the persistent data to be deleted, then just use a standard `java.util.Hashtable` as the container for all your data.